# Dynamic programming: largest weight possible in a path of n nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph

First of all, I would like to say that this is my first question on Stack Overflow and if my question is not asked right or if it is a question I shouldn't be asking, please tell me so I can fix it (I've read the guided tour already but you never know!)

So lets get started: I'm trying to make an algorithm in a directed acyclic and weighted graph (the weight can be negative or positive). The algorithm will have to find the path with the largest weight starting from a specific node and that can go through a maximum of N nodes (it can use less nodes if it will get a better weight).

I understood that I will have to use dynamic programing to do that but I have no idea on how I could do it. I've done quite a bit of research and I've only come up with "longest path algorithm from a node u to a node v" but that isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

I am familiar with Dijkstra's algorithm but I don't think that this is what I am supposed to use.

Thank you very much for reading me and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant that you can only go through N nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm on input v, z:

1. Find strongly connected component, know if you have cycle with positive weight inside a way from node v  you can return infinite
2. Sort the directed graph using dfs
3. Start from the the leaves nodes and return the maximum(weight_of_node(leave1,  z),.....)
4. For the current node print it and pick the father node with the most weigh calculated by a recursive function. If the node has only  one father pick this father, if the node is v return the weight of v and print it
5. Now all the selected nodes are printed

*when you calculate the weight of node

`weight_of_node(x,  z) :

If z==0

```
   return - infinite
```

return      maximum(weight_of_node(father_node1) , weight_of_node(father_node2) ,...) +current_node_weight`, z -  1)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for this answer. I will try to implement it. Although, can I use this algorithm with z being the amount of nodes I can go through? My guess would be that yes I can.

Comment: It's helps you?

Comment: Thank you very much, I put your answer as accepted! I should be able to do it now.